# How to find the conserved quantities of the Kirchhoff equation?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, wave-equation, conservation-laws

Consider the Kirchhoff equation, given by
$$u_{tt}-\left(1+\int_{\mathbb{R}} u_x^2\;dx\right)u_{xx}+f(u)=0, (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_+$$
where $f(u)=u-u^{2r+1}$, for $r \in \mathbb{N}$. How to find the conserved quantitie of this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of them:

- Multiply by $u_x$ and integrate, you get
  $$ \int u_{tt} u_x ~dx = 0 $$
  so 
  $$ \partial_t \int u_{t} u_x ~dx - \int u_t u_{tx} ~dx = 0 $$
  the second term integrates to zero.
- Multiply by $u_t$ and integrate by parts you get
  $$ \int u_{tt} u_t + (1 + \int u_x^2 ~dx) u_{xt} u_x + uu_t - u^{2r+1} u_t ~dx = 0 $$
  This you can rewrite as
  $$ \partial_t \int \frac12 u_t^2 + \frac12 (1 + \frac12 \int u_x^2~dx) u_x^2 + \frac12 u^2 - \frac1{2r+2} u^{2r+2} ~dx  = 0$$

Comment: Why multiplying by $u_x$ and integrante we get only $\int u_{tt}u_x \; dx=0$? And the rest of the terms?

Comment: Integration of a total derivative yields 0. $$\int u_{xx} u_x = \int \partial_x (u_x)^2 = 0$$ and similarly the $f(u)$ terms. $$ \int f(u) u_x = \int \partial_x F(u) = 0$$ where $F$ is the primitive to $f$.

Comment: Very good. Thank you!